# Start an activity depending on the String given?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    private void sendNotification(String message, String uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, xxx.class);
```

How can I change "xxx.class" to use the variable uri and start this activity? I'm using webview sending GCM push notifications with variable "message" and also want to open variable activities.

I get "cannot resolve constructor" in Android Studio if I do this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, uri);
```

Comment: Try leveraging the intent filtering. See more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Resolution).

Comment: The Intent object does not have a constructor that takes two Strings as parameters. It does have a [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri)) that takes a String and a Uri as a parameter.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you can use [Class.forName()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)  method to get what you need.
So it would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(xxx));
```

But don't forget to surround it with `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

When calling Class.forName(), you should use the class name without the extension.  if your class is e.g. MyTest and is in the package mytestpackage.tests, then you should use:

```
Class.forName("mytestpackage.tests.MyTest")
```

Comment: Thank you too, both advices helped me!